# why does my program have 'IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level'?

Tags: python-3.x

im just trying to run a test code for a larger project, but halfway through i got this error.
heres my code, i just want it to work without errors.

```
name=[]
call=[]
position=[]
time=[]
count=0
while True:
    x=[]
    x=input('').split(' ')
    if x[0]=='END':
        break
    elif x[0]=='InsertU':
        name.append(x[2])
        call.append(x[1])
        position.apend('0')
        time.append('0')

    elif x[0]=='InsertL':
        for item in call:
            if item==x[1]:
                position[call.index(x[1])]=(x[2]+x[3])
                name[call.index(x[1])]=(x[4])

print(name)
print(call)
print(position)
print(time)
```

Comment: You probably mixed tabs and spaces somewhere

Comment: You should also post the error trace (I've tested your code and not run into any errors)

Comment: The program is running for me, try copying it from here and pasting it back to the editor.

Comment: also, there is an error line 14, append takes two 'p's

Comment: oh thx. i'll take a look